# @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") not working as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

My application is failing to format date input. I am using com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat

Json Input:

```
"startDate": "2019-08-07"
```

Member variable defined in my class:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") 
private LocalDate startDate;
```

Dependencies:

```
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.0')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.0')
```

Exception seen:

```
Field error in object 'searchCriteriaDTO' on field 'startDate': rejected value [2019-08-07]; codes [typeMismatch.searchCriteriaDTO.startDate,typeMismatch.startDate,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [searchCriteriaDTO.startDate,startDate]; arguments []; default message [startDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'startDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat java.time.LocalDate] for value '2019-08-07'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2019-08-07]]
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @wilkinsona I saw you responding to something similar. Would you be able to help me understand why JsonFormat is not working while DateTimeFormat works just fine? I am using Spring boot version 2.2.2  if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps forget to register the JavaTimeModule with the ObjectMapper?

```
om.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

I don't recognize the exact error message, but de/seriliazation works OK for me with LocalDate and JavaTimeModule; perhaps spring-boot doesn't automatically register Jackson Databind Modules.

And, btw, I don't think the annotation is needed, since ISO date format is the default.

Comment: In this case, I don't have an object mapper. My code is a simple rest API that takes in a simple JSON as input and one of the fields in my POJO is a date. So, while declaring the date property in this POJO, I am using Jackson's @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"). Serialization/De-serialization here is failing. But if I use Spring's @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) , it works fine

Comment: Well, spring-boot has an ObjectMapper, and it can be customized. Just search for "spring boot configure objectmapper" or something similar.